# Repository URL from string parameter in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a scripted Jenkins pipeline. the Jenkins file is fetched from a git repository. I want to parameterize the Repository URL. I have created a String parameter. I tried to access the string parameter in 'Repository URL' field, but is not working. I get an error that the parameter is not a recognised URL. However, i am able to access the variable in a shell script.

For example, if the string parameter is defined as "GIT_URL", I am trying to access it using ${GIT_URL} or ${params.GIT_URL} or ${env.GIT_URL} or $GIT_URL. No luck. Any thoughts. [image]

Answer (score 8):

For me, the only way to resolve this issue was to *uncheck* the **Lightweight checkout** checkbox in the build config.

E.g.
 [image: Example]

Reference: [Pipeline script from SCM does not expand build parameters/env variables for lightweight checkouts](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42971)

Comment: That's help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is `${params.GIT_URL}`. Make sure that you run the pipeline twice, as a change in the job's parameters in `Jenkinsfile` are stored during the first run and then your value is available during the second run.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? How to run the pipeline twice?

Comment: Click on the button "Build [with parameters]" ;-)