# Global variable in Jenkins Repository URL

Tags: variables, jenkins

I am trying to use a global Jenkins variable in the Repository URL field:

```
Repository URL: ${BUILD-PEND-SRC}
```

**BUILD-PEND-SRC** is defined in `Configure System` and a value of a proper URL is set. If I do a shell execution job with `echo ${BUILD-PEND-SRC}` it does display the correct value.

However, when I run the job, I get

```
ERROR: Failed to check out ${BUILD-PEND-SRC}
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E125002: Malformed URL '${BUILD-PEND-SRC}'
```

Which tells me that Jenkins did not resolve ${BUILD-PEND-SRC}.

Comment: What is the command you are using to get the code from SVN ?? have you added it in  single quote??  `'${BUILD-PEND-SRC}'` because the error is coming with them

Comment: I am using the SVN plugin which injects it's own subform in the Jenkins job

Answer (score 0):

I am summarizing the SO answer that solved it for git-based Jenkins pipeline jobs but also applies to svn-based jobs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065165/1994888 (credits go to [@rupesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986579/rupesh)).

### Summary

1. Edit your job config
2. go to the *Pipeline* section
3. go to the definition *Pipeline script from SCM*
4. **uncheck** *Lightweight checkout*

The issue seems to be with the *scm-api-plugin* (see the [bug report](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42971) in the Jenkins issue tracker), hence, it is not specific to a version control system.