# How do I define the parameterized SVN url in the Jenkins SCM pipeline

Tags: jenkins, svn

I used the Pipeline script from SCM method to build, like this:
[image]

Here you need to fill in a svn url, but my svn has many branches, like this:

```
172.20.1.1/testProject/trunk/xxx
172.20.1.1/testProject/branches/xxx
172.20.1.1/testProject/branches/yyy
```

Each of these branches has its own jenkinsfile, so when I submit a new code in a branch, I need to start a new build. When building, I decide which branch to use according to the parameters I filled in, so I put the Repository here The URL is changed to a parameterized format, but it doesn’t work no matter how I test it.such as: **$SVN_URL,${SVN_URL}**, etc.
He will give error
[image]

can you give me some help, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what is happening with the edit queue of this post? It says full!!!

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, your issue is not so much with the job configuration.
Defining a parameterized job and referencing the variable later in that job is fine (no matter the variable format, e.g., `$var` or `${var}`).

However, you seem to suffer from a bug in the underlying pipeline SCM plugin.

I am summarizing the SO answer that solved it for git-based Jenkins pipeline jobs but also applies to svn-based jobs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065165/1994888 (credits go to [@rupesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986579/rupesh)).

## Summary

1. Edit your job config
2. go to the *Pipeline* section
3. go to the definition *Pipeline script from SCM*
4. **uncheck** *Lightweight checkout*

The issue seems to be with the *scm-api-plugin* (see the [bug report](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-42971) in the Jenkins issue tracker), hence, it is not specific to a version control system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it settin base path of url repo

1. Create Globals properties in "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System"
   Name: SVN_URL
   Value : http://172.20.1.1/testProject/trunk/
2. In the job configuration set the repository url base parametrized:
   ${SVN_URL}/xxx
3. Inside SCM configuration in Check-out Strategy: Check the option -> Quiet check-out

Comment: And do you know if this variable could come from one the job's parameter?